# Can I use regular weight font for bold weight?

Tags: html, ios, css, font-face, webfonts

I want to use 2 fonts: "A-Md" and "A-Bd".

"A-Bd" looks bolder than "A-Md", but both "A-Md" and "A-Bd" font actually have regular weight only.

In this situation, I want to use "A-Bd" as bolder font of "A-Md".
I wrote css as:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'A-font';
  font-weight: normal;
  src: local('A-Md');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'A-font';
  font-weight: bold;
  src: local('A-Bd');
}
body {
  font-family: 'A-font';
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

I hope 'A-Bd' to be applied to texts. But, the result texts' font is bolder text of 'A-Bd' and it looks bad.

If I set font to be 'A-Bd', then the texts are fine. I want to use 'A-Bd' as bold text for 'A-font' I defined.

How can I use 'A-Bd' itself as a bold version of 'A-font'?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve with this approach? Why not simply use the fonts, as regular typefaces?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Actually, I am working with some mobile web pages supporting multi languages. It successfully worked when one is regular and the other one is bold. But now I want to use two more fonts for another language. Both are regular fonts and when I use them as the same way, it fails. When I use font-weight:bold, the browser renders texts bold version of bold font I defined('A-Bd'). If it cannot be worked, I should specify font-family:A-Bd for all the bold texts and remove font-weight:bold when supporting only one exceptional language.

Comment: In the question you write “both "A-Md" and "A-Bd" font actually have regular weight only”, so the bold you could get (depending on browser) would be a browser-dependent “fake bold” (synthetic bold). That’s a problem, really, but without more specific data, including some HTML sample and relevant CSS rules, I can’t see what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: What you are trying to do is a little unconventional, especially in terms of design where less is more in typfaces. But you could accomplish it with something like this:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans+Mono);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nothing+You+Could+Do);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bangers);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sonsie+One);

b {
    font-family: 'Nothing You Could Do', cursive;
    font-weight: normal;
    }
p {
    font-family: 'Droid Sans Mono', san-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    }
p#bangers {
    font-family: 'Bangers', cursive;
    font-weight: normal;
}
span.sonsie {
    font-family: 'Sonsie One', cursive;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Then in your body you could apply the other fonts this way:

```
<p>Main font is Droid Sans Mono and other is <b>Nothing You Could Do</b></p>
<p id="bangers">This is Bangers and <span class="sonsie">this is Sonsie</span></p>
```

See my JSFiddle example on this here: http://jsfiddle.net/Incredulous/GpJtP/

Used google fonts from here: https://www.google.com/fonts
Sourced here: http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201012/font-face_tip_define_font-weight_and_font-style_to_keep_your_css_simple/

Comment: I don't think so. According to the page you provided, it seems to be possible to define one font family, 'DroidSerif', and its bold, italic, italic bold type too using different font files. Also, in this way, font-weight and font-family doesn't need to be overridden. I want to do like this with 2 regular weight fonts, but the browser uses not only bold font I defined('A-Bd') but also make it bolder.

Comment: `font-weight:bold` is not a declaration of what the font's actual weight is, but instead of how it should be displayed. See my edits now. And take a look at the JSFiddle example I provided. This should give you the desired result. The tags I've used can be interchanged with more specific tags if you need to use more than 2 fonts. Remember that CSS selectors have a priority level: html tags = 1, class selector = 10, and id selector = 100, and they are additive to get higher priority levels.

Comment: Based on some of your other comments I have updated my [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Incredulous/GpJtP/) to demonstrate more than 2 fonts being used. Let me know if this accomplishes what you are looking for.

Comment: I wrote new [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sN4h9/) from yours to show my intension. The main font is 'Droid Sans Mono' and the bold font is 'Nothing You Could Do'. I could use 'Nothing You Can Do' even though I did not specify font-family:'Nothing You Could Do' but just specify font-weight:bold. It works good and the browser doesn't make 'Nothing You Could Do' bolder. I did the same thing with my A-Bd and A-Md font to use A-Bd as bold font of A-Md, but the browser renders bolder texts of A-Bd. I can't see the difference between the fiddle and my work using A-Bd and A-Md.

Comment: I need to see your fiddle with the fonts you are actually trying to use. You are successfully using a different font when you are **bolding** text, so I don't see where you are still having trouble.

Comment: Yes, the fiddle works fine, and also my page is still broken. I think I found the reason. When the font is loaded from local font, the browser makes it bolder. I installed 'Nothing You Could Do' and see again my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sN4h9/), the browser renders it wrong. Once I use REGULAR 'Nothing You Could Do' as bold font, browser shows BOLD 'Nothing You Could Do' as bold font (and for there's no bold font of it, browser renders faux bold). It seems like bug. I tested on Chrome for Mac, and iOS webview.

Comment: Unless you can host it somewhere and show me your actual code instead of a fiddle (that doesn't use your fonts) I don't think I can help you trouble shoot it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use tags to specify bold: b, strong, em, or any h# tags (for example), you can set these to display 'your bold font' and font-weight: normal;

You can even set these properties together for multiple elements like so:

```
 b, strong, em  {
      font-weight: normal;
      font-family: 'your bold font';
 }
```

Add other classes to the list as necessary.

Comment: Actually, I barely use b, strong tags and I want to specify bold by css. Should I define 2 different font families and specify bold font-family where I want to make it bold with font-weight:normal? Can't I use two different fonts with using only one font family and only different font-weight css properties?

Comment: What you are asking for doesnt seem possible with just the CSS you want to use. 
Is there really no class difference being used between sections that should be bold vs regular weight? (i.e. <p>I am bold text</p><p>I am regular text</p> ) 
If that is the case, then I would recommend bringing in span tags for text that should be bold. (i.e. <p><span>I am bold text</span></p><p>I am regular text</p> with css span {/*bold font settings */})